# Strip all characters from image filename after a dash (-)

Tags: regex, filenames

I have about 1400 images like this.

```
101018-202x300.jpg
100116-215x300.jpg
1000748-300x157.jpg
100138-196x300.jpg
100308-companion-in-surgical-studies-208x300.jpg
100463-Ambroise-Pare-300x216.jpg
100523-Grulee-collection-pediatrics-194x300.jpg
```

I need to strip out all the character after the **FIRST** dash so that it reads like this

```
101018.jpg
100116.jpg
1000748.jpg
100138.jpg
100308.jpg
100463.jpg
100523.jpg
```

I know this can be done with Regular Expressions but I have not a clue where to begin with it?

I am busy [working through this Regex Site to learn more about the topic.](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Apologies, I did not add some of the other more varying examples.

Comment: you don't really need regex for this. it's a simple string operation.

Comment: Edited my post, now that'll match your new ones (also a Demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename capturing the 101018 and rename the file that you used. [NEW (Demo)](http://regex101.com/r/pQ6yY2)

[OLD (Demo)](http://regex101.com/r/rW2mB4)

`(\d+)[\w-]+\.jpg`

EDIT: A second option is splitting by "-" and getting the first parameter.

Comment: Javier, I've added an EDIT to this post which has some more examples of filenames, if you don't mind having a look? I am trying it on that site you sent me which is great.

Comment: Wow, what an awesome site that is. Thanks again Javier!

Comment: I thought it worked Javier but then I checked again and it doesn't strip the filename so it's left with only something like: 100523.jpg

Comment: So using something like Notepad++ Javier, would I use find and replace to run through my list? I have already tried it but it seems to find the entire line. What how do I do the replace part?

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
$_ -replace '-.*(?=\.\w+$)'
```

e.g.

```
PS> -split'101018-202x300.jpg
>> 100116-215x300.jpg
>> 1000748-300x157.jpg
>> 100138-196x300.jpg' | %{ $_ -replace '-.*(?=\.\w+$)'}
>>
101018.jpg
100116.jpg
1000748.jpg
100138.jpg
```

You can simplify the regex a bit if you only have JPEGs or it's always the part between a hyphen-minus and a dot:

```
-[^.]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Using shell and sed..

```
for i in $(ls /path/to/your/images)

do

mv $i $(echo $i | sed -r 's/([0-9]\*)\-.*\.jpg/\1.jpg/g')

done
```

Let me explain what this will do.
`for loop` will take one file for each iteration
`echo $i | sed -r 's/([0-9]*)\-.*\.jpg/\1.jpg/g'` is for changing file names to your desired output.

Comment: Thanks Linux. I will keep this in mind next time I need to do a big Regex problem!